# PHP-How to re display images on website from fetched URL IMGS

Tags: php, fetch

So I'm a bit stuck, and I've been given various solutions, none of which work. Any hotshot PHP folks out there? Here's the deal, I'm trying to get an image to display on my website, from another website, that has a randomly generated IMG. Though I'm actually trying to do this off a personal art site of mine, this example will serve perfectly. 
http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:Random/File

A random image page with an image on it pops up with that link. Now, I'd like to display THAT random image, or whatever image comes up, on another site. The two possible solutions I have encountered is gathering an array of URL LINKS from a given link. And then re displaying that array as images on another site, like a: < a href="https

The code I get back from what I'm talking about looks like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => https ://kfjhiakwhefkiujahefawef/awoefjoiwejfowe.jpg
[1] => https ://oawiejfoiaewjfoajfeaweoif/awoeifjao;iwejfoawiefj.png

)
```

Instead of the print out however, I'd like the actual images displayed, well specifically array [0], but one thing at a time. The code that's actually doing this is:

```
<?php
/*
Credits: Bit Repository
URL: http://www.bitrepository.com/
*/

$url = 'http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:Random/File';

// Fetch page
$string = FetchPage($url);

// Regex that extracts the images (full tag)
$image_regex_src_url = '/<img[^>]*'.

'src=[\"|\'](.*)[\"|\']/Ui';

preg_match_all($image_regex, $string, $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

$img_tag_array = $out[0];

echo "<pre>"; print_r($img_tag_array); echo "</pre>";

// Regex for SRC Value
$image_regex_src_url = '/<img[^>]*'.

'src=[\"|\'](.*)[\"|\']/Ui';

preg_match_all($image_regex_src_url, $string, $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

$images_url_array = $out[1];

echo "<pre>"; print_r($images_url_array); echo "</pre>";

// Fetch Page Function

function FetchPage($path)
{
$file = fopen($path, "r"); 

if (!$file)
{
 exit("The was a connection error!");
} 

$data = '';

 while (!feof($file))
{
// Extract the data from the file / url

$data .= fgets($file, 1024);
}
return $data; 
}




for($i=0; $i<count($arr1); $i++) {
echo '<img src="'.$arr1[$i].'">';
}

?>
```

Solution two, 
Use a file_get_contents command. Which is this:

```
<?php

$html = 
file_get_contents("http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:Random/File");

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$image_src =  $xpath->query('//div[contains(@class,"fullImageLink")]/a/img')
[0]->getAttribute('src') ;
echo "<img src='$image_src'><br>";


?>
```

However, there's unfortunately an error message I get: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type DOMNodeList as array in /home/wilsons888/public_html/wiki.php on line 11. Or, if I remove a "}" at the end, I just get a blank page.

I have been told that the above code will work, but with openssl extension included. Problem is, I have no idea how to do this. (I'm very new to PHP). Anyone know how to plug it in, so to speak? Thank you so much! I feel like I'm close, just missing the last element.

Comment: http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:Random/File will redirect to the actual file... so the second approach should not work, i think.

Comment: Thank you for the response Ricardo. I think the first solution should work. I just need to replace the code that is printing out the text, and just have it instead display the IMGs. I just need to find out how to do it

Comment: Did you noticed that `$image_regex` is empty and `$image_regex_src_url` is assigned twice with the same regex?

Comment: Hm I didn't. Guess I took for granted what I found online. I guess I just enter the URL in one of those, should be simple enough. For being assigned with the same regex, should I just delete one? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to load the random image, and "print it" as an image directly (so you can embed the php file directly on the IMG tag) using this code:

```
<?php
    $html = file_get_contents("http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:Random/File");
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
    $remoteImage = $dom->getElementById("file")->firstChild->attributes[0]->textContent;
    header("Content-type: image/png");
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($remoteImage));
    echo file_get_contents($remoteImage);
?>
```

Get a new file called showImage.php and put this code in it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<img src="test.php">
</body>
</html>
```

Next, go to your browser and get the showImage.php path, and will show a random image fromt he site you asked...

Comment: Ricardo, thanks very much for your input. I'm not sure exactly how to work the code you mentioned, I must admit I'm very average at html/css, and almost clueless when it comes to php. How do I format code exactly to interact the php and <img source=?   I tried some various formats, like php and the img source in a standard html document, and no go. Thanks so much man.

Comment: Just link the source of the IMG to the PHP file (in my example, named getImage.php), like it was a PNG File, with PHP extension.

Comment: Try the new edit in the answer, if thats what you were asking, please select it as correct. Have a good day

Comment: Ricardo, thank you very much for the clear examples above, this is the most clear I have seen yet. I am unable to get it to work however, but I image it's me messing something up. So you said create file showImage.php with the code below it you specified, which is HTML in format. Then, how does it reference the PHP code above it? Do I create a separate file named....whatever.php and place it in the root folder? Sorry, I'm so new to PHP. I feel like I'm super close now though, thank you for the help

Comment: You made the showImage.php instructions for that file super clear, if you wouldn't mind specifying further what to do with the PHP code example above it in terms of the file/file name, that would be super helpful

Comment: I tried having showImage.php have that html looking text. Then another php file in the same root folder named test.php, with the php code, but nothing will generate on either files when I open

Comment: Create 2 files, the first one, with the first code, and name it test.php, the second file you have to create, is another called  showImage.php, in the same directory. Now, open the second file in the browser.

Comment: Hm, did do that. Getting a broken image however, as you can see:  http://www.wilsonschlamme.com/test/showImage.php      Thoughts? It occurred to me that there's a refrence to png in the php code, I wonder if it needs to be flexible to accommodate jpg as well. But, I hit refresh several times, eventually a png should have popped up.

Comment: Also, not sure if it matters, but if I open up the test.php I get this error message 
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type DOMNamedNodeMap as array in /home/wilsons888/public_html/test/test.php on line 5

Comment: what php version u using?

Comment: Hm good question. My hosting service seems to say NATIVE 5.4.     5.5 and 5.6 are additional options.

Comment: oh my gosh, i switched it to 5.6 and it worked! Hah, how weird my hosting would have an old version by default. Anyway, Ricardo, thanks so much man! You've been super super helpful and clear with examples, while other people often just confused me. I'd like to fine tune it some, and actualy display in text the title of the image file like wiki does, as well as make the img smaller (though that I think I have enough css/html knowledge to do). Thanks again!

Comment: adjusting size was super easy, just did. I'll clean up this page with the comments and the explanation for the fix. thanks again Ricardo